# Special case: integral of finite input signal to ODE is equal to the integral of the solution of the ODE (Solved/short proof found)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, laplace-transform, convolution

I'm trying to show that

$$\lim_{t \to \infty } \int_{0}^t w(\tau) \mathrm{ d } \tau = \lim_{t \to \infty } \int_{0}^t u(\tau) \mathrm{ d } \tau $$

When $w(t)$ is the solution of the ODE,

$$\dot{w}(t)=-w(t)+u(t), \quad w(0)=0$$

for any continuous, finite signal $u(t)$.

I would like to know if anyone disagrees with my (inelegant) proof:

We start with the solution of $\dot{w}(t)$:

$$w(t)=\int_0^t e^{-(t-\tau)}u(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau~,$$ remember that the initial condition is zero

We proceed with taking the Laplace transform of the convolution integral where,

$$w(t)=(h \star u)(t)~, \qquad\text{  and}\qquad h(t)=e^{-t}$$

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}[w(t)]&=\mathcal{L}[(h \star u)(t)]\\
                W(s) &= H(s)U(s), \quad \mathcal{L}[e^{-t}]=H(s)=\frac{1}{s+1}\\
 &=\frac{1}{s+1}U(s)
\end{align}
now we integrate by dividing by the Laplace operator  $s$

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}[\int_0^t w(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau] &=\frac{1}{s}W(s)\\
&=\frac{1}{s}\frac{1}{s+1}U(s)\\
&=\frac{1}{s^2+s}U(s)\\
&=G(s)U(s), \quad G(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+s}\\
\end{align}

We now go back to the time domain

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{1}{s}W(s)] &=\mathcal{L}^{-1}[G(s)U(s)] \\
\int_0^t w(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau & = (g\star u)(t) \\
&=\int_0^t (1-e^{-(t-\tau)}) u(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau, \quad \mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{1}{s^2+s}]=1-e^{-t}\\
&=\int_0^t u(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau - \int_0^t e^{-(t-\tau)}u(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau
\end{align}

We already know that

\begin{equation}
\int_0^t e^{-(t-\tau)}u(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau=w(t)
\end{equation}

So we can substitute it into the previous equation such that

\begin{align}
\int_0^t w(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau & = \int_0^t u(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau - w(t)
\end{align}

Before we take the limit of the above equation, we look on the steady state of $\dot{w}(t)$

\begin{align}
\dot{w}(t)&=-w(t)+u(t) \\
0&=-w(t)+u(t) \\
w(t)&=u(t) \implies \lim_{t \to \infty} w(t)=u(t)
\end{align}

We can now proceed with taking the limit as $t$ approaches infinity

\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t w(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau &= \lim_{t \to \infty} (\int_0^t u(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau - w(t))\\
&=\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t u(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau - \lim_{t \to \infty} w(t), \quad \lim_{t \to \infty} w(t)=0 \\
&=\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t u(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau
\end{align}

Since $u(t)$ is a finite signal that eventually will be zero as time approaches infinity, the limit of $w(t)$ is also zero.

Now that you've read my "proof", can you see any cheating/incorrect operations? Even if it could be shown in an easier way, is my way of reasoning correct?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE, problem is solved**

After discussion with a friend, the proof indeed has a lot simpler and elegant solution. It is as follows
integrate both sides of the ODE and let $t$ go to infinity:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t \dot{w}(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau=- \lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t w(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau+\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t u(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau
\end{equation}

We know already that the ODE becomes stationary as $t$ approaches infinity, hence we can set the left hand side equal to zero and rearrange the equation and we obtain

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t w(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau=\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t u(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau
\end{equation}